# How to resolve entity when using saxon

Tags: xpath

I am using saxon to process my xpath, but sometimes xml file comes with namespace declaration which make my class to throw exception.
Is there any way to ignore namespace while using saxon as we do with dom i.e

```
builder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver()
        {

            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId,
                    String systemId) throws SAXException,IOException
            {

                return null;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use namespaces in your XPath, you can use `local-name()`, for example:

```
/pref:root/pref:element1[@attr="value"]/pref:element2
```

If you have the above XPath (with namespaces) you can also write is as this:

```
/*[local-name() = "root"]/*[local-name() = "element1"][@attr="value"]/*[local-name() = "element2"]
```

This will allow you not to use namespaces

Comment: The question mentions "Saxon" in the title, assuming it is Saxon 8 or 9 supporting XPath 2.0 you can also use `/*:root/*:element1/*:element2` instead of using a predicate with local-name.